# Woocommerce / wpml add different version of same currency

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, currency, wpml

I use WooCommerce & WPML for my client. The website have different prices for different markets.

For example, the EU is a price and for Finland there is another price both in €.

I have included a separate version of currency called FI-EUR. Everything appears right and works just the way I want.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'finland_euro' );
function finland_euro( $currencies ) {
     $currencies['FI-EUR'] = __( 'Finland Euro', 'woocommerce' );
     return $currencies;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'FI-EUR': $currency_symbol = '€'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

But the problem arises when we use Stripe or Paypal. Since it does not support FI-EUR. How do I change FI-EUR to EUR for stripe?

I can not overwrite EUR as there is another price.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, `FI-EUR` isn't a real currency, right, it's something you've invented? So naturally Stripe and PayPal don't recognize it — you'd need to implement your separate prices in a more [normal fashion](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/handle-multiple-regions-currencies-woocommerce/)

Comment: @karllekko thank you for your comment. But the problem is my client use wpml. The only way I can add two different prices in same currency is add custom Currency. EU countrys have one price in euro and finland has a other price in euro.